# PHP PDO SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So situation is this , on localhost all seems working (mamp pro) and there are no issues at all , but when i upload it to a server it gives me an error :

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

Don't really know what this means, searched around on net but found no solution.
here is how i'm making the connection to database:

```
define("SERVER_SQL_VERSION","mysql");
define("SQL_SERVER","localhost");
define("SQL_PORT","3306");
define("SQL_USERNAME","userdb_new");
define("SQL_PASSWORD","92384923jjdhasj");
define("SQL_DB_NAME","usernew_db");
define('PREFIX', 'tb_');
if(!function_exists('pdoConnect')) {
function pdoConnect() {
    $pdo = new        PDO(SERVER_SQL_VERSION.":host=".SQL_SERVER.";dbname=".SQL_DB_NAME."",   "".SQL_USERNAME."", "".SQL_PASSWORD.""); 
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    return $pdo;
}
}
$db = pdoConnect();
```

Any help regarding this would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Are the connection details (specifically hostname and port) valid for the server too?

Comment: yep all details are valid only host name i edited for posting as question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am trying to understand this:

```
$pdo = new PDO(SERVER_SQL_VERSION.":host=".SQL_SERVER.";dbname=".SQL_DB_NAME."",   "".SQL_USERNAME."", "".SQL_PASSWORD."");
```

But I get lost in the double quotes. What are they doing there? Try this:

```
$dsn = SERVER_SQL_VERSION.':host='.SQL_SERVER.';dbname='.SQL_DB_NAME;
$pdo = new PDO($dsn,SQL_USERNAME,SQL_PASSWORD);
```

Comment: Don't know what this did but it works :). thnx mate ;)

Comment: Well, what a surprise, I wasn't sure about this at all. Anyway, I think it looks a lot better this way.

Comment: maybe some quote or anything, well thnx :=)